# Forward declaration of a method return type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Suppose I have the following class:

Foo.h:

```
class MyVectorClass;

class Foo {
public:
    MyVectorClass get();
    ...
}
```

Following the commonly agreed pattern to forward declare everything that can be forward declared, and since `MyVectorClass` is used only as a return type of a method, `MyVectorClass` is forward declared. Then, any user of this class should include `MyVectorClass.h` to be able to use the method `get`.

Bar.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "MyVectorClass.h"

Foo foo;
...
MyVectorClass result = foo.get();
```

The fact that in order to use class `Foo` we need to include some additional headers makes me question the idea of a forward declaration here. This is even more confusing for me if I use auto instead of `MyVectorClass`, which is preferable since I don't really care about `MyVectorClass` much, anything with a vector-like interface is good enough for me.

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#include "MyVectorClass.h"

Foo foo;
...
auto result = foo.get();
```

When reading this code, it's very hard to find out why do we include `MyVectorClass.h`. And when the interface of `Foo` changes, and `get` starts to return `AnotherVectorClass`, or `std::vector`, we should remove the old `MyVectorClass.h` in every user of the get method and include an appropriate new header instead.

Is forward declaration really worth it here?

Comment: `auto` is not a run-time dynamic, but deduced at compile time. So in order to use `result` (regardless of `auto`), you need to have the full definition of `MyVectorClass` available.

Comment: If you don't care about the actual type, just about its interface, why don't you do it the STL way and give `foo.get` a pair of iterators, or an `insert_iterator` that will fill a caller-supplied structure?

Comment: @crashmstr I am aware of what `auto` is, and I don't want run-time polymorphism, I want compile-time polymorphism. The fact that I need the full definition is the reason why I have this question, since the general advice of avoiding the full definition when a forward declaration suffices seems to have a downside in this situation.

Comment: @swatmad while the forward declaration may be sufficient in `Foo.h`, is it not sufficient in `Foo.cpp` or `Bar.cpp`. But if `Foo.h` actually includes the header that declares the class, then the using code does not need to have an include for that as well (Assuming there is no usage of `MyVectorClass` without using `Foo`).

Comment: "the commonly agreed pattern to forward declare everything that can be" I challenge the notion that this is commonly agreed. I strongly disagree with it. It leads to lots of useless bookkeeping work and code duplication. Don't forward declare anything that you don't need to for a very good reason.

Comment: @RobK Well, most of the books, blogs and answers on StackOverflow state more or less the following: "Don't #include a definition when a forward declaration will do" (this is a quote from "C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices", but every source I've seen so far states something similar), so I had an impression that it's the other way around: that this is the kind of default thing you should stick to unless you have some specific reasons.

Comment: That's a *much* narrower recommendation than "forward declare everything that can be". In practice, I think you'll find it's pretty rare to have a declaration of a class suffice in lieu of #including the header. You'd only be able to use pointers and references to the class, and how useful is that going to be?

Comment: I agree with Rob K, which is also my answer for your question: No, it is not always the best to forward declare classes. I do use forward declarations within headers, but only for classes where the include would cause cyclic dependancies. All others are included. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is saying that anything that *can* be forward-declared *should* be. Forward declarations gives benefits in terms of compilation speed, but at the expense of convenience.

One example is the one you gave. Another is that even IDEs and tools (such as VisualAssist) sometimes don't know what to make of a forward-declaration, and are not able to jump to the actual type. The same goes for refactoring tools.

So the question of is it worth it or not depends on whether or not the compilation speed improvement would be worth it.

If you want to give a slightly better hint to users of the class, there's another option: you can include all of its dependencies in a "Foo.inl" file, which users would need to include in order to use it safely, without too much hassle, and in a more future-proof way.

Answer (score -1):

Again, `auto` is statically typed and won't help you get the desired dynamic polymorphism. If you need it, you should use iterators or pointers.

So one solution here will be to inherit all of your `SomeVector` implementation classes from the same base class so you wouldn't need to worry about editing the includings every time you change something.

Alternatively, you can work with the data that `get()` gives you first hand, provided `MyVectorClass` has proper iterators, and never use the intermediate `SomeVector` type at all. This is better for your case, as you can also use the stl vector itself.

Comment: Polymorphism has nothing to do with the problem here. The issues are: 1) the implementation of `Foo.h` _may change_ in the future, switching to another type of vector, coming from whatever library (hence you have to change the include in `Bar.cpp`), and 2) using auto makes it very unclear why we have to include `MyVectorClass.h`.